# No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; Django project tutorial 2

Tags: python, django

So, I've been following the tutorial steps here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/ and I got to the step where I am supposed to run this command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
python manage.py makemigrations polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in_find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/tgumm/pythonenv/tutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/home/tgumm/pythonenv/tutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/home/tgumm/pythonenv/tutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/tgumm/pythonenv/tutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/tgumm/pythonenv/tutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/home/tgumm/pythonenv/tutorial/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_an``d_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2221, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; 'polls.apps' is not a package
```

Here are my models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 164):

The first problem is this warning in the traceback:

```
No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'
```

That means that you are missing a comma after `'polls.apps.PollsConfig` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. It should be:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django....',
    ...
)
```

The second problem is the warning `'polls.apps' is not a package`. That suggests that you have installed Django 1.8, but you are following the Django 1.9 tutorial.

If you are using Django 1.8, then follow the 1.8 tutorial so that you don't hit problems like this. Adding the polls app to `INSTALLED_APPS` is [covered here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models) in the Django 1.8 tutorial. Note that it doesn't use `PollsConfig`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'polls',
)
```

Comment: I had almost the exact same problem.   But, for me I had misspelled my class name.   And ShogunT, if the answer solves your problem, will you accept the answer?

Comment: This is the right answer for the question... I had made exactly the same mistake as the OP.  I don't think I've ever seen so many "almost right" other answers coming and confusing the "comma issue" ... add to that that yours was the first answer chronologically.  Odd.

Comment: Commas and Semi-Colons are nightmares.

Comment: OMG - YES!  :ROFL:

Answer (score 44):

```
ImportError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'
```

You forgot to add ',' in the list

Answer (score 33):

check for comma "," after 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'

Comment: Awesome. Fixed my issue!

Answer (score 14):

You just missed a comma after `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'`.

Don't worry, it happens for the best of us!

Answer (score 14):

Anyone who is getting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pollsdjango'

And INSTALLED_APPS :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**Solution:**

You forgot to add comma(,) at the end of line 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig', <----this comma
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27139

Description

In tutorial 02, Writing your first Django app, part 2, typing in

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
   ....
```

will cause an ImportError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'; 'polls.apps' is not a package

This is resolved by instead putting

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls',
   ....
```

Comment: Solved my problem. But my django version is 2.0.4, python version 3.6.5. According to the document, django will generate apps.py since version 1.9 ...So don't know why

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a similar error: **ImportError: No module named 'polls'**

The cause was that I stored my apps inside the "apps" directory.
The solution is to change the code inside apps.py

from:

```
class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
```

to ("apps" is the name of my django apps directory):

```
class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.polls'
```

Answer (score 2):

you forget to add "," after  'polls.apps.PollsConfig'  ","
must include a comma "," ... 'polls.apps.PollsConfig',

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you come from [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/) Tut here's the problem You just missed a *comma* after **'polls.apps.PollsConfig'.** so it should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ....
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above/below fix your problem and you came here with the same errors make sure that you do not have a `__init__.py` in your top level directory. Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score -1):

If we are getting error regarding `not a package` than most of the time it may happen that we missed to add `__init__.py` file within the directory where we are getting this error.