# How do I solve: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named error when starting Django shell" error

Tags: python, django

When running 'python manage.py shell', I'm getting the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; 'polls.apps' is not a package
```

I have tried another solution where I had to use `./manage.py shell --plain`, but it's does't work. Also tried a solution that stated the ipython version wasn't correct, but that solution didn't solve anything for me either.

Comment: Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35484263/8865579

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'polls.apps.PollsConfigdjango'; Django project tutorial 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484263/no-module-named-polls-apps-pollsconfigdjango-django-project-tutorial-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your Python code. Django cannot be started because the configuration is invalid. One of your `INSTALLED_APPS` is broken. A hint what could be wrong is given in the traceback.

For the actual error is, you need to figure it out yourself, as it would probably involve copy-pasting a lot of code from your project here and would not be a good fit for StackOverflow Q&A format.

Comment: Forgot a comma in the INSTALLED_APPS list.